# This small printf loop emits one extra byte seemingly out of nowhere, why?

Tags: c, printf, stdio

This self-contained program, when run with the windows command line (i.e. `test.exe > test.txt`), emits an extra byte for reasons I cannot understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        printf("%c%c%c", (int)(i / (float)N * 255), 0, 255);
}
```

One would expect test.txt to have 150 bytes, but it has 151. Looking at it with a hex editor you can see this:

```
0000 ff05 00ff 0d0a 00ff 0f00 ff14 00ff     
1900 ff1e 00ff 2300 ff28 00ff 2d00 ff33
00ff 3800 ff3d 00ff 4200 ff47 00ff 4c00
ff51 00ff 5600 ff5b 00ff 6000 ff66 00ff
6b00 ff70 00ff 7500 ff7a 00ff 7f00 ff84
00ff 8900 ff8e 00ff 9300 ff99 00ff 9e00
ffa3 00ff a800 ffad 00ff b200 ffb7 00ff
bc00 ffc1 00ff c600 ffcc 00ff d100 ffd6
00ff db00 ffe0 00ff e500 ffea 00ff ef00
fff4 00ff f900 ff
```

The third iteration of the loop seems to be the culprit where four bytes are instead emitted: `0d0a00ff`. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this would happen. I compiled this with Visual Studio 2015, in case that matters.

Comment: Somehow it looks like this output is not from this program. `0d0a` is an end of line combination, which can't result from the program presented. *Update:* - apparently it can as the answer is stating...

Comment: stdout is a text stream, it automatically translates \n to \r\n.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a way to turn this effect off?

Comment: Sure, use %x instead of %c so you are actually printing text.  Or fopen() so you have full control over the stream you write to.

Comment: It seems like there are three choices that will work:  (1) Don't use stdout, but instead open an output file in binary mode, (2) Use an OS that has true redirection support without corrupting the data (i.e. anything other than Windows), or (3) Don't try to redirect binary data, but stick to a text format.

Comment: Maybe `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);`? I haven't paid close attention to [the POSIX description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html), but at a glance it appears it can work. Try putting it as the very first statement in `main()`.

Comment: @pmg The Windows `freopen` is not POSIX-compliant; a null path is invalid.

Comment: @molbdnilo `freopen()` treating `NULL` as an invalid path is not just non-POSIX-compliant, it's [non-C-compliant](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4) and [non-C++-compliant](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdio.syn#:%3cstdio.h%3e).  And not surprising.

Comment: @TomKarzes Using the cygwin command line also works. But it's an annoying workaround. I will just write directly to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(int)(2 / (float)5 * 255)` is 10, which is the ASCII representation of the newline character, which Windows translates to its normal CRLF representation.

There is no way to avoid this behaviour (`freopen` is limited on Windows) as far I know, but seeing as you want to write binary data, using the text-formatting function `printf` and standard output is perhaps not the ideal approach.

Comment: Windows! I spent 10 mins reproducing and nearly pulled my hair out! Of course, I haven't coded for Windows in ages...

Comment: Why is it doing it for IO redirection? Is it because of the `txt` extension? Or it is doing it always? How do we get binary stream redirection?

Comment: I guess Windows has a strong text vs. data distinction.  It sounds like this wants to be treated as data and not text.  Or better yet, just don't use Windows.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is standard output, and I imagine on Windows standard output is text mode.

Comment: You're probably correct. Is there a way to turn this off? Is this something that automatically happens because it is piped through the windows command line?

Comment: As far as I know, Windows thinks everything is text unless told otherwise.  And  I assume redirection is iffy under Windows.

Comment: This is not done by Windows.  It is the C runtime library that maps C conventions to OS line endings, printf("hello world\n") style.  The basic reason why fopen() has a mode argument.  And freopen(), works to change stdout to binary mode.

Comment: @HansPassant *This is not done by Windows. It is the C runtime library ...*  True, but it's the C runtime on Windows and Windows only that does this (At least for non-rare implementations. And I'm sure there are ways to make an IBM mainframe's C runtime do even worse...)